# Sorting a list by a referenced field react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I started using `react-admin` and is basically works fine. However I have some trouble using the `ReferenceField`.

The REST API I'm calling returns e.g. the following JSON data:

**/language**

```
{
  "language": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Language #0"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Language #1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Language #2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Language #3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**/myreferences**

```
{
  "myreferences": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "langauge": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Language #0"
      },
      "name": "My reference #0"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "langauge": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Language #1"
      },
      "name": "My reference #1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "langauge": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Language #2"
      },
      "name": "My reference #2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And that's how map this in react-admin.

```
export const LanguageList = props => (
  <List
    title="Languages"
    sort={{ field: "name", order: "ASC" }}
    filters={<LanguageFilter/>}
    {...props}
  >
    <Datagrid>
      <NumberField source="id" label="ID" />
      <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
); 

export const MyReferenceList = props => (
  <List
    title="My References"
    sort={{ field: "name", order: "ASC" }}
    filters={<MyReferenceFilter />}
    {...props}
  >
    <Datagrid>
      <NumberField source="id" label="ID" />
      <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
      <ReferenceField source="langauge.id" reference="language" label="Language">
        <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

My problem is that the references are shown correctly but when I click on the column for the referenced language name react-admin sorts by the language's ID instead of its name.

What do I need to adapt so that sorting by name is working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<ReferenceField>` component accepts a `sortBy` prop, which specifies the field to use for sorting instead of the `source`. So in your case, you can write:

```
      <ReferenceField source="language.id" sortBy="language.name" reference="language" label="Language">
        <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>
```

This is explained in the React-admin documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencefield